# Pegar o atributo de um elemento

Tags: javascript, css

Como faço para selecionar a cor do backGround do elemento div?

Obs: Usando javascript

```js
var cor;
cor = document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor;
```

```css
#bloco1 {
    width: 280px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang 'pt-br'>

    <head>
        <title>Pintar</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='bloco1' onclick='selecionarCor(this.id)'></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Quando usas [`el.style.backgroundColor;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) estás à procura de *inline styles*, ou seja estilos defenidos diretamente no elemento. Por exemplo assim:

```
<div id='bloco1' style="background-color: #00f;"></div>
```

Nesse caso näo te vai dar nada pois o teu CSS não está *inline* mas sim como CSS num ficheiro à parte.

Deves usar [`window.getComputedStyle(el).backgroundColor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). E já agora, se passares apenas o `this` à função já tens o elemento que queres, não precisas do `document.getElementById`.

```js
function selecionarCor(el) {
    var cor = window.getComputedStyle(el).backgroundColor;
 alert(cor);
}
```

```css
#bloco1 {
    width: 280px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang 'pt-br'>

    <head>
        <title>Pintar</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='bloco1' onclick='selecionarCor(this)'></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Procurei exemplos sobre o assunto, porém não tinha ficado claro, agora entendi. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @RobisonAleixo otimo que pude ajudar! Se quiseres podes marcar a resposta como aceite.